# How can I get stereo mix for my Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card, stereo

I'm trying to get stereo mix with Windows 7 Professional on an HP G-series notebook. I right-click the volume icon -> Recording devices -> Check show disabled devices, but nothing new comes up. My sound-card is a Conexant high definition smart audio 221. I've tried many drivers but none seem to do the trick. Is there a way to get it on here? If not, are there any sound-cards that are known to have stereo mix support?

Answer (score 0):

If the Sound driver does not allow for it, there is nothing you can do other than try other drivers, which you have done.

Since it is a laptop, your only choice would be some sort of USB sound device, unless it has some sort of card slot available.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking for. If you want to change the volume of each speaker independently, then go to Control Panel>Sound>Speakers>Properties>Levels>Balance